# JavaScript Number class is not working in Eclipse IDE

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I created a Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse IDE 2019-12 and Apache Tomcat 8.5.55 server, where a user can give integers as input and will get their sum as output. The HTML file has a JavaScript function to check for empty, non-numeric and non-integer inputs before sending it to the Java EE servlet.

As the checking happens before sending request to the servlet, the servlet will throw errors if it receives anything other than an integer.

I used the `Number.isInteger(x)` method to check if the input is an integer. However, when I run the HTML file in Eclispe, the `Number` class in JavaScript doesn't seem to be working in the IDE. Any mention of the `Number` class seems to be causing the IDE to ignore the `if` blocks and sending the wrong data to the servlet. But checking using the Number class works fine in any browser, as it should.

Below is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Addition Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div
        {
            position:       absolute;
            top:            10px;
            left:           100px;
            width:          250px;
            height:         120px;
            border:         2px solid green;
            border-radius:  20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function valueEntryValidation() // Should allow only integers. No empty, character or floating point inputs allowed
        {
            var int1 = document.AdditionForm.integer1.value;
            var int2 = document.AdditionForm.integer2.value;
            if (int1 == "" || int2 == "")
            {
                alert ("Fields cannot be empty");
                return false;
            }
            // Only the if statement below works properly in Eclipse IDE
            // if (isNaN (int1) || isNaN (int2) || int1.indexOf (".") > -1 || int2.indexOf (".") > -1)

            // The if statement below works fine in browsers, but not in Eclipse IDE
            if (isNaN (int1) || isNaN (int2) || !Number.isInteger (Number (int1)) || !Number.isInteger (Number (int2)))
            {
                alert ("Enter integers only");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="AdditionForm" action="AdditionServlet" method="get" onsubmit="return valueEntryValidation()">
        <div>
            <br>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Integer 1</td><td> <input type="text" name="integer1"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Integer 2</td><td> <input type="text" name="integer2"/></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td colspan="2" align="Center"><input type="Submit" value="Add"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I fix this problem with the IDE?

Comment: Does "However, when I run the HTML file in Eclispe" involve the internal browser, or an external browser? You should use an external one if you want to make sure the latest APIs and standards are supported at runtime.

Comment: I am running it by clicking on the run button in the IDE. It opens a browser inside the IDE. This is just a simple project to get to know how Java Servlets work, so no APIs involved yet. But I expect it to have the standards built-in as the IDE itself is used in industry standards.

Comment: Check your web browser preference page in Eclipse and set it to an external browser.

Comment: I solved it myself. Thanks for your help though, nitind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem for me was probably incompatible versions of Eclipse IDE's components.

Eclipse lets you install softwares that are required for a type of project from a URL of their software's repository, it's the `Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development` in my case. I installed Eclipse a long time ago and installed the softwares for older version, which did not get updated when Eclipse updated to the latest version. I had to manually install the components for the version.

**First**, update Eclipse by going to `Help->Check for Updates`.
**Next**, go to `Help->Install New Software` and put the URL `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/<Eclipse-version>/` in the `Work with:` field.
**Finally**, install the softwares required and restart Eclipse.

This is what worked for me. Hope this helps you too.